# starting plone instance: Error: '$' not followed by '$' or name

Tags: plone, instance, startup, process.start

I was working on my Plone instance and at a certain moment I was not able to stop/start my instance anymore.

```
./bin/instance start

Error: '$' not followed by '$' or name
```

What's the meaning of this error?

Comment: Sounds like your last buildout broke your instance script and you're getting a shell error now. Did you change anything noteworthy in your `buildout.cfg`?

Comment: Do __bin/instance fg__ for more information

Comment: Take a look at your `zope.conf` (usually in `parts/instance/etc/zope.conf`), but be aware that finding and fixing the error there will not solve your problem, since it's re-generated by buildout. It'll tell you what part of your `buildout.cfg` needs looking at, though.